# AnkhSVN - managing VS *projects* not *solutions*

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I work on several different software projects and I started building up some generic libraries with utilitarian functions that I use in all of them. Recently I had three or four projects going at once at different physical locations and it got painful to synchronize the libraries manually.

So I figured I should create a repository for these libraries so I can access them from anywhere. I'll sit down one final time to synchronize them between projects, commit them, and from now on I'll have the repository to make sure I keep things straight and keep the most recent version of the library working with all the relevant projects.

Because I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 I went with AnkhSVN. To my dismay, it does not seem to allow you to manage only projects within a solution---only the entire solution!

I go by the instructions [here](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html); they're pretty clear. There is some minor confusion in that an SVN "project" is not a Visual Studio "project", apparently.

So I select a project in the Solution Explorer, right click on it, and select "Add Selected Projects to Subversion...". The window that pops up uses the *solution* name for the field labeled "project name". That's a sign of trouble, but I can manually change it to be the actual *project* name. Then I can choose a repository, and create a folder for this *project*. So far so good.

But then for "local folder" it's a drop down list with the default selection being the location of the *solution*, and the only other options are moving farther up the tree. If I leave it as is and hit OK, AnkhSVN wants to put the entire solution in that directory I created (assumingly only for the selected *project*).

In fact if I select "Add Solution to Subversion..." I get an identical window.

I want Subversion manage only certain projects within a solution. With local solutions, that's how I make sure I keep my libraries universal; instead of just linking to the build I add the entire source to each solution so changes are "global". Now I need to do this for solutions at physically different locations and apparently AnkhSVN won't let me do this? Is it broken or is this by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this has been known since 2008 and the developers don't think it's important enough of an issue.

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&dsMessageId=152095

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'standard' way of providing a UI to handle this situation, but if you just checkout your working copies and bring all of the projects in a single layout AnkhSVN will just provide all the tools to work on this project.

The really hard problem -where we as AnkhSVN team are working on- is how we can provide the necessary UI to work with this kind of layouts easily. There is no easy way to layout your project if it is made out of different trees that live in different parts of your harddrive.

A workaround for some projects might be to create a parent working copy with externals (`svn:externals`) pointing towards the separate projects. In that case checking out the rooot project will automatically bring in the other projects.

Comment: How about if the different trees didn't live in different parts of the hard drive? What I mean is if I start with a blank solution folder, then via Tortoise or svn.exe do an SVN checkout from an existing project in SVN to a sub-folder, then go into VS and Add - Existing Project and point to what was just checked out. Now all the projects are in the same folder. Multiple VS solutions would have their own working copies of the single SVN "project".

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed in this way.

Before make a solution with all projects follow the steps.

1. For each projects add them separately to svn (each projects with
   it's own directory structure in svn)
2. Make a solution
3. Add each desired projects to solution.

In this way you can commit changes just to desired project and commits are not bundle to solution.

Later on you can easily separate projects from solution (delete, move to other solutions, etc).